# Issue using aura:unescapedHtml

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, html

I am trying to display some preformatted HTML data as rows in a table. If I copy the whole string from the controller and paste it into my component it renders correctly. But using aura:unescapedHtml does not seem to work.

cmp code

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_col-bordered" style="margin-left: 250px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.columns}" var="c" indexVar="key">
                    <th style="width: 15px;">
                        <div style="writing-mode: tb-rl">{!c}</div>
                    </th>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.tableData}"/>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Controller Code

```
var action = component.get('c.getAllCrewCompStatus');

        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            debugger;
            var crewComps = response.getReturnValue();
            var size = Object.keys(crewComps).length;
            var table = '';
            for(var c = 0; c < size; c++){
                var tableRowofComps = crewComps[c];
                table += '<tr>';
                for(var t = 0; t < tableRowofComps.length; t++){
                    //This is where check for formatting will happen
                    table += '<td>';
                    table += tableRowofComps[t];
                    table += '</td>';
                }
                table += '</tr>';
            }

            component.set("v.tableData", table);
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

[image]

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_col-bordered" style="margin-left: 250px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.columns}" var="c" indexVar="key">
                    <th style="width: 15px;">
                        <div style="writing-mode: tb-rl">{!c}</div>
                    </th>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!--<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.tableData}"/>-->
            <tr><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>S</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>S</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>S</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>S</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>S</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>S</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>S</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>S</td><td>S</td><td>C</td><td>S</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

^^^This produces output I expect vv

[image]

aura:unescapedHtml with the exact same data returned by the controller vv
[image]

Comment: tableData attribute of type string?

Comment: Have you tried simply using https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedRichText/documentation formattedRichText .Might be helpful

Comment: From docs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:unescapedHtml/specification I see that "It's intended for outputting pre-formatted HTML, for example, where the formatting is arbitrary, or expensive to calculate. The body of this component is ignored, and won't be rendered. " could this be the issue?

Comment: Thanks @MohithShrivastava, that helped me figure out that the reason it wasn't working is because the <tr><td> tags were being sanitized by the component because they are not being output between <table> tags. Even though they actually are, im guessing it has to do with what the DOM has finished loading at that point.